# Serial.readString and added text Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

can somebody help me solve this? Arduino code.

I need to get ASCII text into string from serial read.

```
getdata1=Serial1.readString();   ///  the variable contains text from serial ASCII, this is working for me
```

then how to do something like this:

```
String getdata1 = (getdata1 && "!OK");  // I need attach after readed text from serial another text
```

if I resend it as `Serial2.println(getdata1 && "!OK");`
I will receive 1, but not the text.

How can I get text from the variable getdata1 readed from serial and combine it with another text, then resend it as Ascii text to another serial port?

thank you

Daniel

Comment: You can use `+` or `concat` to append text as per the manual: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator

Comment: String getdata1 = (getdata1 + "!OK") Should do the trick